# Returning to specific fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am developing an application which is based on Fragment and main activity implements the Slide navigation. I have got three fragment."A", "B", "C" Let say I traverse from "B" fragment to an independent activity. When I try to return from Activity, it lands me up on "A" Fragment where as I want to return to same fragment from where I traversed to activity.

I am using the below code to transact with Fragments

```
if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
```

How to do this?

Comment: You need to use popBackStack and Backstack entry count to redirect where you want

Comment: Could you please let me know the code and position to use this?

Answer (score 1):

check it out my below code,

```
   @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {

            //your code goes here

            } else if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                fm.popBackStack();
                //your code goes here

            } else {
               fm.popBackStack();
                //your code goes here
            }
        }
```

count return number of fragment you have crossed, comment it if you need any help

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're dealing with pretty common in Android and they've explained in a [good article in the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

So basically, you want to use the `BackStack` but for your specific issue, there is another solution: when you're moving to the other activity, the original one (which contains B) is basically not destroyed so, what you could do is put states in this activity (the one containing A, B and C) and, as soon as, you come back from your independant activity, your `onResume` will be fired and you just have to override it to make it display the fragment you want.

Comment: How to do this to put states?

Comment: I would do an enum something like `enum STATE_OF_ACTIVITY {FRAGMENT_A, FRAGMENT_B, FRAGMENT_C}` and then have a `STATE_OF_ACTIVITY s` in your parent `Activity` and change it Everytime you call the `FragmentManager`